# req.files is empty when trying to upload a file to server with node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file

HTML:

```
<form action="/uploadpic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" data-clear-btn="true" name="image" id="new_pic" value="" placeholder="Choose File">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" style="width:30%">
</form>
```

NodeJS:

```
app.post('/uploadpic', function(req,res) {
console.log(req.files);
console.log(req.body);});
```

I also use:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./uploads'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }))
```

in the console I get:

```
{}
{}
```

i dont seem to understand what could be the problem here.. thanks !

Comment: Which version of Express are you using? I have used BodyParser for file uploads with Express 3*

Comment: I use Express 3. how do you use body parser for file uploads ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   var fs = require('fs');

    app.post('/uploadpic', function(req,res) {

    //req.files contains array of files iterate and get it
    //if it has only one. it is like object

    //here is the code for object

    if (req && req.files) {

     var contentType = req.files.file.type;    
     var fname = req.files.file.name;    
     var image_path = req.files.file.path;    
     fs.readFile(image_path, function (err, data) { 
      var data = data; //this is your data use this
     })

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

BodyParser doesn't include file uploads. You need to use something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty).

Also express (4.0+) doesn't come bundled with middleware anymore, so you'll need to use [bodyparser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) for POST requests.